# Windows gc replace shows \n instead of new line

Tags: string, powershell

This is what I use in PowerShell 5.1:

```
(gc test.txt) | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '^(.*)(\r?\n|$)', '^(.*)(\r?\n|$)', 'this is a repl $1\ntest tex $1 test$2'} | Set-Content test2.txt
```

This is `test.txt`:

```
ok
ok
ok
```

This is the current `test2.txt`:

```
this is a repl ok\ntest tex ok test
```

While it should be:

```
first ok
second ok third
```

I also tried this but got the following error:

```
sed -re "s|^(.*)(\r?\n|$)|this is a repl $1\ntest tex $1 test$2" test.txt > test2.txt
```

Error:

```
/usr/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unknown option to `s'
```

I also tried this (this works in Linux but not in Windows):

```
sed -e "s|^(.*)(\r?\n|$)|this is a repl $1\ntest tex $1 test$2" -i test.txt
```

```
/usr/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unknown option to `s'
```

How to find and replace regex?

I searched google and stackoverflow and tried some commands but they showed `\n` like above in my question.

Comment: Inside single quotes in PowerShell, no string escape sequences are supported. You need to use *double quotes* and then use backtick+n to insert a newline. So, use ``"this is a repl `$1`ntest tex `$1 test`$2"``

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried but it does not work. The output now removes `ok` but new line is acted fine. I mean something like: `this is a repl (empty here)`(new line), `test (empty here) tex`.

Comment: I see `ok` in the relaced text, I used ``(gc test.txt) -replace '^(.*)(\r?\n|$)', "this is a repl `$1`ntest tex `$1 test`$2"``

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oops, I used `\`$1\`\`n` and `\`$1\`` (two backticks instead of one only before `n` and `$`). It works now, thanks:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside single quotes in PowerShell, no string escape sequences are supported. `'\n` is a sequence of a literal `\` followed with a literal `n` char.

You need to use double quotes and then use backtick + `n` to insert a newline, i.e. `` "`n" ``. So, use

```
"this is a repl `$1`ntest tex `$1 test`$2"
```